# Apache RewriteRule to a password protected network path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using the following RewriteRule, that works fine if the specified folder is public, and does not require a user/pass:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/video/(.*) //10.42.1.51/qnap/SessionVideos/$1 [T=video/webm]
```

However, if that folder is not public, I receive an Error 404. Is there any way to work around this? Like pass in the username/password in the path (eg add @user:pass), or a global setting in Apache that allows to specify credentials when accessing restricted folders?

Comment: Can you give an example of the rule that "works fine". I think you are getting a 404 simply because the URL-path `/10.42.1.51/qnap/SessionVideos/<whatever>` (the double slash prefix is resolved _away_) does not exist in the current vHost. You can't rewrite to a local "network path" like that using mod_rewrite. If the rewrite was happening as intended and the target directory was password protected (although you've not stated the method of authentication) then you would expect a 401 or 403, not a 404?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/video/(.*) //10.42.1.5/public/$1 [T=video/webm]` works, because it is a publicly accessible folder. Or so I thought. Reason why it actually works is because `10.42.1.5` is the IP of the **local** machine! If I try this with a **public** folder on another IP in the LAN, I get the same Error 404.
So I guess you are right when you say that Apache can't rewrite to a local network path. I  tried mapping it to a drive letter `RewriteRule ^/video/(.*) Z:/$1 [T=video/webm]`, but that created Error 400. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure why the "400 Bad Request"... try enclosing in double quotes, ie. `"Z:/$1"`. You should also be using the `L` flag on that rule. Do you have any other rules? However, you also need to grant access to `Z:/` in Apache (otherwise you will get a 403, or possibly a 400). How is the target protected by user/pwd? Is this at the Windows/OS level?

Comment: Tried puting `"Z:/$1"`, tried using `L` flag - did not fix Error 400. In the error log it says `AH00126: Invalid URI in request 'Z:/video.mp4'`.
Sorry for my ignorance, how would I grant apache access to `Z:/`? What setting/mechanism?
I am using a QNAP share, that is password protected - I am not sure, what method that is, but in Windows you get the typical user/pass prompt dialog, if you want to enter that folder.
Anyway, the folder I am experimenting with right now is an ordinary windows share (full access) - no user/pass required. So that is not the cause of Error 400.